# Process ends before expected Python

Tags: python, mongodb, process

I am writing a simple Python program in Pycharm that imports a csv database to a Mongodb, shows a progress bar while importing and, after being imported all documents, run some other functions...

Since I use a subprocess instruction to run mongoimport command I must do some waiting for the other functions not to be executed before the mongimport.

**Here comes the issue:** if I use subprocess.wait() the progress bar stops updating until the mongoimport ends, else if I use sleep() the same happens...

So I tried to run mongoimport subprocess and the functions that updates the progress bar in the same process. Then I use an "empty" while loop checking if process.is_alive() so the main program does nothin, while the process is importing and updating the progress bar...  BUT it exits the loop before expected! Long before the mongoimport neither the progress bar function end.

Here is the code:

```
def mainFunction(self):
    process1 = Process(target=self.execc())
    process1.start()

    while process1.is_alive():
        print("IM IN PROCESS 1")

    # THIS IS PRINTED BEFORE "execc()" ENDS
    print("IM OUT!")

    # other functions
    self.toISO()
    self.createFrec()
    self.sort()


def execc(self):

    p = subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '-d', 'tfg', '-c', 'myCol', '--type', 'csv', '--file', './myFile.csv', '--headerline'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


    # shows and updates the progress bar while mongoimpor
    self.showProgress()


# RECURSIVE FUNCTION
# updates the progress bar every 200ms
def showProgress(self):
    bytes = self.db.command('collStats', self.coll_name.get())
    self.pBar['value'] = bytes['size']

    if bytes['size'] < self.maxbytes:
        self.pBar.after(200, self.showProgress)
```

Comment: by the way, `process1 = Process(target=self.execc())` is false. It should be `process1 = Process(target=self.execc)`. Your code just execute, so there is no subprocess ro tun

Comment: omg... I feel terrible right now... I changed it but it happens the same: although mongoimport is still running, showProgress() do not works and the while loop breaks...

Comment: where's the `wait`-call you mention above? Inside `execc` you create subprocess and then you don't wait for it to exit.

Comment: I removed the wait because I want both, subprocess and showProgress() function, to run at the same time. I just want to wait for the #other functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a multiprocessing approach to handle this case.
Instead you can simply use `Popen.poll` to check whether the subprocess has terminated. I think something like this should work

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '-d', 'tfg', '-c', 'myCol', '--type', 'csv', '--file', './myFile.csv', '--headerline'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while p.poll() is None:

    # shows and updates the progress bar while mongoimpor
    self.showProgress()

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception("mongoimport terminated with exit code {}".format(p.returncode))
```

Comment: thanks for your help.... however, notice that showProgress() is a recursive function, furthermore if I put the function inside a while loop, it is gonna be executed maaaaaany many times :/

Comment: just add a `sleep(0.2)` and remove the recursion